# How to efficiently place RSUs of a SUMO scenario in OMNeT++?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to perform an experiment for vehicular ad hoc networks using Omnet++ (v 5), Veins (v. 4.4), and Sumo (v. 0.25.0). I use [LuST Scenario](https://github.com/lcodeca/LuSTScenario/releases/tag/v2.0) as a realistic mobility trace. I would like to place RSUs optimally throughout the entire region, e.g., at the intersections and square, or at the places with high traffic density. As far as I know, we cannot place RSUs during runtime.

Of course one can identify the longitude and latitude and manually set them in the configuration. But is there a more efficient way to place them?

Comment: Technically, placing nodes at runtime is a straightforward task. Regarding *optimal* placement, whole papers have been written on that. A quick Google search turns up 10.1002/int.21890 and https://doi.org/10.1109/ColComCon.2016.7516394 to give two of many examples.